# Simple javascript loop doesnt work as intended

Tags: javascript, loops

I want my trigger to activate every 2 seconds, but each time with my value of i.
Like first 3 seconds trigger .slide1, after another 3 seconds .slide2 etc...

Here my code :

```
    setInterval(function () {
     for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        $('.slide'+ i).trigger('click');
    }   
}, 3000)
```

After 3 seconds it immediately trigger my .slide4 and i was wondering why ?

Comment: Simply because it is what you wrote. :)

Comment: Every time the function is called you tell it to trigger the click on all your slides.

Comment: After three seconds, your for loop is running in it's entirety, so all of your slides are triggering the click

Comment: Btw. this is a regular JavaScript for loop, not a jQuery loop (e.g. `$.each()`) - the thread subject is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now my logic is hurt... Hah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var slide = 0;
setInterval(function () {
        $('.slide'+ (slide++ % 5)).trigger('click');
}, 3000);
```

The problem with your code is that each time the interval function is called, you execute the loop and trigger the `click` event for all the slides.

Comment: Could you explain why you used modulo here ?

Comment: @Oliboy50 this way you can keep the counter (`slider` variable) between 0 and the number you divide. In this case 0-4.

Comment: Clever. But are you sure that there will be no issue if user stay on this page a long long long time, cause of the slide integer limit value ?

Comment: @Oliboy50 the max integer is `9007199254740992`. To reach that by incrementing every 3 seconds, takes approximately (*if my calculations are correct*) 856 million years ;)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks for pointing the max integer value ;)